# Location Permisison on ios not showing

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework

I'm working on an angular mobile app that runs in ios by using the ionic framework.

I want the "Always authorise access to location" option to appear in the settings. And just that. I don't care about the user notification, I just want to manually be able to set the geolocation to "always.

I've updated my `Info.plist` file with the following lines:

```xml
    <key> NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Always allow Geolocation?</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Always allow Geolocation?</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow Geolocation?</string>
```

However, the option still does not appear in the settings.

Am I missing something?

For context: I am completely new to development for ios.

Comment: It isn't enough just to add the strings to your plist. Your app has to actually *request* the permission before the option to change the permission appears in the apps settings.

Comment: The plug-in you are using doesn't support "always" location; I looked at its source code and there is no way that it can make an "always" request.

Comment: it works in Android though. Is it somethign specific to ios?

Comment: Android doesn't have a specific always/background permission. iOS does and this plug-in doesn't support it.

Comment: Android does have a specific "always" permission: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6179507?hl=en

 But noted regarding iOS

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that you need to add the NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription key to your Info.plist file in order to enable the "Always" option for location access. for example  how you can update your Info.plist file to include this key:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Always allow Geolocation?</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Always allow Geolocation?</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow Geolocation?</string>
```

Make sure to save the changes to your Info.plist file and rebuild your app to see if the "Always" option appears in the settings.

Comment: it's already there (line 1 of my code snippet)

Comment: Do you install plugins properly
like.
`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation`
`npm install @ionic-native/geolocation`

Comment: I'm using capacitor/geolocation, and it seems to work fine (I can retrieve the location, just not in the background because of the absence of the right permission).

Comment: it's mean your code look like this.
`import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {}

// Request "always" permission
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 30000, maximumAge: 3600, desiredAccuracy: 0 })
  .then((resp) => {
    // Location data
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error getting location', error);
  });`

Comment: I'm using capacitor, so it's rather:
`import {Geolocation} from '@capacitor/geolocation'
const coordiantes = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().catch(....) `

Answer (score -1):

I think you've miss understood how permissions work on iOS.
This string is for showing the user the reason why you're asking for permission.
You still need to ask for location permission you can't bypass it and you should follow best practises around location prompts.
Swift code

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/requesting_authorization_to_use_location_services

Comment: I'm asking for permission. I just don't do it with swift, as I'm using angular paired with ionic framework and capacitor

Comment: Are you sure you are asking for permission?
It won't appear in settings until permission has been requested. (Either denied or allow when in use, allow all the time)